# Combining `handout` with `allowframebreaks`

Tags: beamer, lyx, handout, allowframebreaks

I'm writing some slides using the Beamer template.

In order to get all my bibliography entries displayed, I added the `allowframebreaks` option to my bibliography frame.

However, since I have `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` at the beginning of my slide, all but the first bibliography item are greyed out. In order to set all bibliography items to be visible, I am attempting to combine this with `handout`, which I seem to be unable to do.

Currently, my LyX document looks like this

[image: LyX document]

... and the output looks like this

[image: Output]

Help me tex.stackexchange. You're my only hope. My Thesis defense slides hang in the balance

Comment: Hello! I think that may be if  you provide a minimal working example ( starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document`) that reproduces the issue you will get a faster answer!

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda: As I am working with LyX, I have no LaTeX code with which to demonstrate a MWE. Hopefully the attached screenshots help clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay specifications are not supported with `allowframebreaks`

Try to add `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}` inside the bibliography frame (at the begining)

**In the code below the bibliography items are taken from the beamer documentation**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
[allowframebreaks=0.8
]
{My bibliography}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{} % <---------
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Salomaa, 1973]{Salomaa1973}
A.~Salomaa.
\newblock {\em Formal Languages}.
\newblock Academic Press, 1973.
\bibitem[Dijkstra, 1982]{Dijkstra1982}
E.~Dijkstra.
\newblock Smoothsort, an alternative for sorting in situ.
\newblock {\em Science of Computer Programming}, 1(3):223--233, 1982.
\bibitem[Salomaa, 1973]{Salomaa1973}
A.~Salomaa.
\newblock {\em Formal Languages}.
\newblock Academic Press, 1973.
\bibitem[Dijkstra, 1982]{Dijkstra1982}
E.~Dijkstra.
\newblock Smoothsort, an alternative for sorting in situ.
\newblock {\em Science of Computer Programming}, 1(3):223--233, 1982.
\bibitem[Salomaa, 1973]{Salomaa1973}
A.~Salomaa.
\newblock {\em Formal Languages}.
\newblock Academic Press, 1973.
\bibitem[Dijkstra, 1982]{Dijkstra1982}
E.~Dijkstra.
\newblock Smoothsort, an alternative for sorting in situ.
\newblock {\em Science of Computer Programming}, 1(3):223--233, 1982.
\bibitem[Salomaa, 1973]{Salomaa1973}
A.~Salomaa.
\newblock {\em Formal Languages}.
\newblock Academic Press, 1973.
\bibitem[Dijkstra, 1982]{Dijkstra1982}
E.~Dijkstra.
\newblock Smoothsort, an alternative for sorting in situ.
\newblock {\em Science of Computer Programming}, 1(3):223--233, 1982.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]